# Надо ли использовать кавычки при наименовании гостиниц?

Tags: пунктуация, ономастика, кавычки

В первом примере понятно, что кавычки нужны, потому что это условное наименование:

> — Встретимся в гостинице «Обезьяна».
> — Хорошо! До встречи!

Но вот с другой стороны, если не используется слово «гостиница», то надо ли сохранять кавычки в тексте? Пример:

> — Встретимся в Обезьяне.
> — Хорошо! До встречи!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*...если не используется слово «гостиница», то надо ли сохранять кавычки в тексте?*
Конечно надо, обязательно надо!
Правильно:
*— Встретимся в «Обезьяне».

— Хорошо! До встречи!*

Гостиница — это родовое слово, "Обезьяна" — название, заключенное в кавычки ([имя собственное](https://bigenc.ru/linguistics/text/3588774)).
В отсутствие родового слова данное название гостиницы склоняется, кавычки остаются (куда ж им деваться-то?).

В их планы вовсе не входили встречи с соотечественниками, поэтому поселились не **в «Прибалтийской»** или **«Октябрьской»**, а **в «Ленинграде»**, где иностранцев больше, чем советских. [Михаил Гиголашвили. Чертово колесо (2007)]

Поздно приехали в Таллин, с трудом получили номер **в «Паласе»**. [Давид Самойлов. Поденные записи (1934-1869) (1965)]

Как-то поздно ночью, когда я уже вернулась к себе в номер **в «Англетере»**, умылась и легла спать, раздался стук в дверь. [Рина Зеленая. Разрозненные страницы (1981)]

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение!